# Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of len function

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, migrations

Estou mapeando uma propriedade para o banco do tipo xml usando `Migrations`.

```
public string Xml { get; set; }

this.Property(t => t.Xml).HasColumnName("Xml").HasColumnType("xml");
```

Porem, ao consultar a classe usando Linq retorna o erro.

```
 _context.PreListaPostagemLog.Where(p => p.IdPlp == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Xml)).ToList();
```

> Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Comment: Como é a consulta?

Comment: Coloquei acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No SQL Server, [`len()` não funciona com o tipo XML](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2013/05/16/len-and-datalength/). Você vai precisar usar `datalength()` no lugar.

No Entity Framework, `datalength()` se usa assim:

```
_context.PreListaPostagemLog
        .Where(p => p.IdPlp == null && SqlFunctions.DataLength(p.Xml) > 0)
        .ToList();
```

[Veja mais sobre `SqlFunctions` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Obrigado ! Funcionou perfeitamente.